# Observable<Any> triggers TSLint 'property does not exist'

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, rxjs, tslint

I have this block of code here:

```
this._auth.getToken().flatMap(token => {
  return this._http.post("/authenticate");
}).flatMap(res => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append("Authorization", res.json().Token);
  return this._http.get(this.endpoints[endpoint], {headers: headers});
});
```

*http.get* and *http.post* return an *Observable<Response>* which contains a *.json* method

However *flatMap* returns an Observable<Any> which doesn't contain the *.json* method.

It works correctly, but TSlint complains with:

> Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.at line 32 col 49

Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected? It's not a big deal but maybe it's a symptom of bigger issues in the code.

Comment: Try with `.flatMap((res: Response) => ...)`

Comment: It works! Thank you. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I posted it as an answer as you suggested. I'm curious about the version you're using (both angular2 and TS), which ones are you using?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0"
"typescript": "^1.7.3"
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0"
"tslint": "^3.1.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue you should add `Response` as the type of the returned value

```js
flatMap((res: Response) => {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append("Authorization", res.json().Token);
  return this._http.get(this.endpoints[endpoint], {headers: headers});
});
```

**Note**

This was fixed already, check this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5597#issuecomment-162081391), so pressumably you're not in the newest version. I tested it using beta.0 and I couldn't reproduce this message even without adding `Response` as the type.

**Reference**

- [RxJS #635](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/635)
- [Angular #5597](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5597)